# Elastic search 6.2 query not yielding correct results with filters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "should": [
    {
      "dis_max": {.........}
    }
  ],
  "filter":  [
        {
          "term": {
            "city": "default_city"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "used_for": "sell"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "category": ["C1","C2"]
          }
        }
      ]
}
}
```

However, the results yielded also contains documents with "used_for" field "non-sell",  making filed "used_for" as a keyword type, stopped yielding any results altogether. Please let me know what wrong am I going here.

Answer (score 0):

With the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), "non-sell" will be stored as two tokens: "non" and "sell", and so a search for "sell" will match.
If you make the field a keyword type, that should resolve your problem, but bear in mind a search will have to match the whole field, any whitespace and is case-sensitive.
If you switch to a [whitespace analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html), your hyphens and case will be preserved, but not whitespace.